# Один input для всех

Tags: javascript, html

Есть несколько `input`

```
<input type="number" class="amount_int" name="amount" value=""/>
<input type="radio" class='radio-button' name="amount" value="1.00" id="sem3">
<input type="radio" class='radio-button' name="amount" value="5.00" id="sem">
<input type="radio" class='radio-button' name="amount" value="10.00" id="sem2">
```

Дело в том что для коректной работы пейпал, должен быть один инпут c name="amount", по этому нужен дополнительный `input`с названием amount, но как ему передовать значение?

Comment: ну так эти инпуты удалите и всё. Как передавать значение? Миллион способов, пользователь что сам не может ввести? Или js'ом введите.

Comment: Ну не я это придумал, а мне сделать надо) должны быть готовые варианты 1, 5, 10, + чтобы можно было ввести в ручную

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Самый простой вариант - оставить один значимый инпут, а по другим так или иначе обрабатывать значение onClick.

Обработку ручного ввода не привожу. Вопрос же не в нём.

```html
  <input id="amount_val" type="number" class="amount_int" name="amount" value="" />
  <br /><span><input type="radio" value = "1.00" name="amount-tmp" onclick= "javascript:document.getElementById('amount_val').value=this.value;">
1.0</span>
  <br /><span><input type="radio" value = "5.00" name="amount-tmp" onclick= "javascript:document.getElementById('amount_val').value=this.value;">
5.0</span>
  <br /><span><input type="radio" value = "10.00" name="amount-tmp" onclick= "javascript:document.getElementById('amount_val').value=this.value;">
10.0</span>
```

Comment: Брррррр.. `label`? `javascript:`?

Comment: @Qwertiy, отмечено в первом же комменте - вариантов миллион.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery.

Вот пример:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("input:text").val("Glenn Quagmire");
    });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Name: <input type="text" name="user"></p>

<button>Set the value of the input field</button>

</body>
</html>
```